# using Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json not found in Rider

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

I'm trying to use:

```
using Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json
public static List<Level> GetLevels()
{
    var asset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("levels.json".Replace(".json", ""));
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Level>>(asset.text);
}
```

and `JsonConvert` is in red.
and `Plastic` is showing in red. It says cannot resolve symbol Plastic.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I did install Newtonsoft.Json version 13 as assembly. No luck.

EDIT: using Newtonsoft.Json; also red.

Answer (score 5):

Ok after some digging:

Apparently updated unity project which wiped out the dependency that was added via package manager > add package from git URL

Unity forgot a documented change for this. So, the answer:

**`Package Manager Window > Add Package from GIT URL > com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json`**

And **instead** of using `using Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json`

use `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

NOTE: On an older project where this was added manually, Newtonsoft Json wasn't showing up in the package manager > Packages: In Project until I went to the Cog Wheel > Checked Show Dependencies.